# gtk_widget_show_all(window); not working when waiting on a function to return a value

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am making a dart game, and I have created the whole layout of the game page. I want to await a dart hitting the board, which can take a variable amount of time, then update the score for that dart, update the remaining points the player has left, and update the round score.

I make the layout, call gtk_widget_show_all(window);, then call await_dart_hit();

The window does not show until the dart hits though. It's as if the window can't show until the whole function ends, but I have tried making the window in a separate function, then returning, then calling await_dart_hit(); and this doesn't work either.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void problem_causing_wait(){
    while(1);
}

void start(){
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Start");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),1000,400);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    problem_causing_wait();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window, *button, *button_box;

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Welcome!");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),1000,400);

    button_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button_box);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Get Started");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (start), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button_box),button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return(0);
}
```

If you run this code, you'll see that once you click the "Get Started" button, it freezes. It doesn't show the "Start" window despite showing all before calling the problem_causing_wait() function.

Please help!

compiled with: gcc main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: This app runs in a single thread, so when you call `problem_causing_wait` you enter an infinite loop which prevents all the following code from execution. What exactly causes "dart hitting the board"? A mouse click event, something you get from the network, etc?

Comment: A physical dart will actually hit the board. The raspberry pi 3 has I/O pins that detect the dart hitting the board. The code will interpret it as a "1" on an input pin. The await_dart_hit() function just reads all of the input pins in a loop waiting for one of them to return a "1"

Comment: And I understand that the infinite loop will prevent the following code from running. That's why I call gtk_widget_show_all(window); before I call the loop. After the window is shown, no other code needs to run until the dart hit is detected

Comment: Once a "1" is detecting, signifying a dart hit, await_dart_hit() changes a global variable that contains the most recent dart throw value and then it exits the loop. So once all three darts for the round are thrown, the program unfreezes because it isn't waiting for a dart anymore. Then you click next player and it freezes again until the next player throws.

Answer (score 1):

As your application is running in a single thread this function "problem_causing_wait" acts as a blocking function and stops the main loop.

i think using "g_idle_add" and "g_thread_new" might solve your problem.

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

void *problem_causing_wait(){
    while(1);
    //update the Ui using g_idle_add
    return NULL;
}

void start(){
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Start");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),1000,400);

    g_thread_new("dart-game",problem_causing_wait,NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window, *button, *button_box;

        //Initilizes Support for Concurrent Threads
    XInitThreads();

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Welcome!");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),1000,400);

    button_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button_box);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Get Started");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (start), NULL);
    //g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button_box),button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to freeze the UI. Freezing the UI means no refresh, even if a refresh is needed. For example if you move another application on the foreground, then move it away, your app still has to repaint. You also can't show a countdown of the time remaining to shoot the dart. Due to that, you can't handle cases when a player completely misses the target (here, you should probably either interact with the UI or let the turn countdown expire with some feedback).

Instead, don't use threads at all, and use `g_timeout_add` to check every 500ms if a dart hit the board, letting the GTK+ main loop handle the polling of your I/O.